# Set Timer For Windows phone 8 App Using XAML With C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing windows phone 8 game app.

I need To add  countdown time functionality into my app.

like when application start. Timer Value Show 60,59,58....0

When 0 Reach Show Msg "Time Out".

I searched in Google but i don't have any idea.
[may be it's my mistake not searching in correct way]

I try with following code it's show the date and clock values like [3/12/2014 6:22:10 PM]

C# Code

```
 public SensorTwo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DispatcherTimer newTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        newTimer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        newTimer.Start();
    }

 void OnTimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        clock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

XAML CODE

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="22"  Name="clock" Width="350" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
```

any One help or Guid me To Complete This Functionality...

Comment: You need a counter and you need to show the time also? is that your requirement?

Comment: @JagathMurali No My Requirement Is Just Show 60,59...0 only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//make global declaration of a counter variable 


 int counter =60;    
    void OnTimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
       {       
         counter --;
         if(counter<0)
         {
          newTimer.Stop();
          counter=60;
         }
        else
         {
          clock.Text =counter.ToString();
         }
       }
```

Comment: In Line Number 6 newTimer - Where I Declare ?

Comment: @Gurunathan declare newTimer globally as well

Answer (score 1):

Declare a counter which will reset once the app starts

```
TimeSpan counter = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
```

This in the OnTimerTick()

```
counter -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);   
clock.Text = counter.Seconds;
```

Hope this will help

Comment: This will statically works , means like , you need to click every time on a certain button to decrease the timer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

clock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("ss");

Comment: Sorry it's Possible To Work? it's just Show SS