# Text in Textblock to change Dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
HubSection Tag="2" Name="Stopwatch" x:Uid="Stopwatch" Header="STOPWATCH"

DataContext="{Binding Groups[1]}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">

<DataTemplate>

 <Grid>

<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,36,11,350" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00:00:00" 


VerticalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Width="320" Height="63" BorderThickness="0" 

Foreground="White" Background="Black" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="42" CharacterSpacing="80" 

FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"/>

</Grid>

</DataTemplate>

        </HubSection>
```

This Is the XAML PART

```
stopwatch_timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
stopwatch_timer.Tick += Stopwatch_Tick;
TimerDisplay.Text = Start_Count++.ToString();
```

My question is how to increment zero of textblock?

Because when I run this all zeros vanish and it increments from single zero.

Comment: Though I am not sure what are you trying to do in the C# code, but what if you set TimerDisplay.Text = stopwatch_timer.Interval? Try showing the TimeSpan value itself, as you need, so that the time format would be preserved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Timer For Windows phone 8 App Using XAML With C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352346/set-timer-for-windows-phone-8-app-using-xaml-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, this might help you:

```
private TimeSpan time;
private void Timer()
{
     DispatcherTimer stopwatch_timer = new DispatcherTimer();
     stopwatch_timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
     stopwatch_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(stopwatch_timer_Tick);
     stopwatch_timer.Start();
     time = stopwatch_timer.Interval;
}        
void stopwatch_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TimerDisplay.Text = time.ToString();
     time = time.Add(((DispatcherTimer)sender).Interval);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Timer tick event handler for showing the time.

```
// creating timer instance
DispatcherTimer newTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
// timer interval specified as 1 second
newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
// Sub-routine OnTimerTick will be called at every 1 second
newTimer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
// starting the timer
newTimer.Start();
```

Here is code for `OnTimerTick`

```
void OnTimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
        // text box property is set to current system date.
        // ToString() converts the datetime value into text
        TimerDisplay.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Go through this link http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Implement_timers_in_Windows_Phone